# preg_match_all separated by commas with values probably containing spaces

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I currently have a `preg_match_all` being used on regular strings that contain no spaces but I now need to make it work for anything between each space.

I need `abc, hh, hey there, 1 2 3, hey_there_` to return
`abc` `hh` ``` hey there``1 2 3 ``` `hey_there_`

But my current script just stops when a space is involved.

```
preg_match_all("/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)+[,]/",$threadpolloptions,$polloptions);
foreach(array_unique($polloptions[1]) as $option) {
     $test .= $option.' > ';
}
```

Comment: Why not just split by `\s*,\s*`

Comment: Could you post example? not so good at this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need regular expresion in this case. Explode will be faster

```
$str = 'abc, hh, hey there, 1 2 3, hey_there_';
print_r(explode(', ', $str));
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => abc
    [1] => hh
    [2] => hey there
    [3] => 1 2 3
    [4] => hey_there_
)
```

**UPDATE**

```
$str = 'abc, hh,hey there, 1 2 3, hey_there_';
print_r(preg_split("/,\s*/", $str));
```

result the same

Comment: What if a user submits it like this `one,two, three, four, five,six`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode` along with `array_map` as

```
$str = 'abc, hh, hey there, 1 2 3, hey_there_';
var_dump(array_map('trim',explode(',',$str)));
```

[**Fiddle**](https://eval.in/393145)

Comment: @Uchiha I was too lazy to add it to the answer +1

Comment: @splash58 I thought of the same thing

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode():

```
$string = "abc, hh, hey there, 1 2 3, hey_there_";
$array = explode(',', $string);

foreach($array as $row){
    echo trim($row, ' ');
}
```

Comment: What if a user submits it like this `one,two, three, four, five,six`

Comment: I update a answer. You will separate by ',' and then trim a spaces in loop.